# Alternatives to Facebook Feed Pull in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So we've had an app that we pulled user feeds a few different ways; however thanks to Facebook dropping permissions and blocking a few, all these ways we pulled the data is now gone.

I'm wondering if anyone using Koala Rails gem has an alternative, a work around.

I've noticed that in Facebook on your own account, you can pull feeds of pages you are subscribed to. Such as;

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/feed
```

However, I don't see how to pull that in the Graph Explorer for a user or even 'me' as being the user;

```
/v2.2/me/pages/feed/
```

doesn't really work at all. Any suggestions or ideas? maybe someone has a work around to grab feeds with certain different permissions.

Comment: That does indeed not exist in the API. `/me/home` would get closest, as it is supposed to mirror a user’s news feed; but reading that would require `read_stream` permission, and that you will not get granted in review any more for any platform for which an official FB client already exists (and that includes web).

Comment: @CBroe I'm wondering if there's an API for that web FB client which pulls it ... not understanding why FB took that permission out. There's a lot of apps relying or that did rely on the read_stream permission.

Comment: Apart from limiting what user data apps can get their hands on, I’d assume that they want people to use their own “clients” (which would be facebook.com for web), rather than having apps replicate core functionality.

Comment: @CBroe yeah well; there's a lot missing in how people can use Facebook and connect. I guess its all in the details what Facebook wants to be and how external 3rd app connected it wants to be.